# Reading data from GUI table in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to design a simple GUI via tkinter.
I've inserted a 2D table where I can feed the data and now I would like to access the entered data in order to use them further in the program.
Can someone please help me with that?
In the following image you can see the table I'm working with:
[image]
And here you can look at the code I'm using to make this table looks like this:

```
 
    height=5
    width=2
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            b=Entry(window, textvariable=Intvar()
            b.grid(row=i+1, column=j)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 2D list to store the `IntVar` used for those `Entry` widgets:

```
height=5
width=2
varlist = [[IntVar() for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        b=Entry(window, textvariable=varlist[i][j])
        b.grid(row=i+1, column=j)
```

Then later you can use `varlist[i][j].get()` to get the value for required entry.